# How to calculate number of values in a particular range in an array of doubles

Tags: c++

For example, I have an array of doubles and I want to search for values that are equal to 2.0 but since it is an array of doubles it is difficult to find exact values so I want to find values in the range 2-1e-10,2+1e-10. I have seen some people do it using upper_bound and lower_bound.
How do I do that?

Comment: upper  bound and lower bound are not for this

Answer (score 1):

Just use a predicate:

```
std::count_if(
    begin(array),
    end(array),
    [](double v) { return std::abs(v - 2.0) <= 1e-10; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already defined your bounds or threshold for accepting a value, why not just write

```
if ( val > 2-1e-10 && val < 2+1e-10 ) {}
```